# Measure of disc given product measure and Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability

Consider the product measure on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ obtained from the Lebesgue measure in one dimension. Show that the disc with center $(1/2,1/2)$ inscribed inside the unit square is measurable. What is the measure of the disc?

Any help with how to start this would very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the continuous (and hence measurable) function
$$
f(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-1/2)^2 + (y-1/2)^2}
$$
Then the set in question is
$$
D = \{(x,y) : f(x,y) < 1/2\} = f^{-1}([0,1/2))
$$
Since $[0,1/2)$ is a measurable set, so is $D$.

Its measure is its area : You can prove this by approximating it from the inside by regular $n$-gons, and taking their limit (using the fact that the lebesgue measure is continuous w.r.t to taking unions)